# How to access a List property of a swift class from an Objective C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

I have this swift model class (using Realm) that has a simple `String` property and a `List` of strings. I can easily access the string property from an Objective-C class, but it doesn't seem to work when I try to access the `List` property.

Code:

```
class MyClass: Object, Mappable {

   dynamic var stringProperty: String?
   let listOfStrings = List<StringValue>()

}
```

I tried creating a getter method that returns a simple array from the `List` property, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Can you post your getter method, how you're calling it from Objective-C, and specifically how it "didn't work as expected"? Using Realm Swift from Objective-C isn't technically supported, but there's no reason your approach (abstractly stated) would necessarily fail.

Comment: Well, it did work actually but I wished there was a better lightweight solution.

Answer (score 1):

One of the first things that the [Realm Swift documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) says is:

> If you’re looking to use Realm from Objective‑C, *or from mixed Objective‑C & Swift apps*, please see Realm Objective‑C instead. The Realm Objective‑C and Realm Swift APIs are not interoperable and using them together is not supported.

There is some [limited, unofficial support for interoperability with Objective-C available](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v2.8.2/RealmSwift/ObjectiveCSupport.swift#L21-L30) that may help you, but it's really intended for only very narrow use cases (primarily to allow writing frameworks that wish to support models written in both Realm Objective-C and Realm Swift). The general advice is that if you want to access your Realm models from both Objective-C and Swift, use Realm Objective-C.